# Net.WebRequest taking so much time and does not finish to get response

Tags: .net, webrequest

Whenever using the WebRequest to test internet connection works fine. However while attemping to connect to internet (after shuting down wifi) and have **wifi's status** to `"no access to internet"` IF  I do the webrequest again it just doesn't work. 
I have debugged and found the issue is exactly on line:

```
objResp = objWebReq.GetResponse
```

It just takes to long and does not finish.

Below is the function to test the connection:

```
Dim objUrl As New System.Uri("http://www.google.com")
Dim objWebReq As System.Net.WebRequest
objWebReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(objUrl)
Dim objResp As System.Net.WebResponse = Nothing
Try ' Attempt to get response and return True
   objResp = objWebReq.GetResponse
   objResp.Close()
   objWebReq = Nothing
   Return True
 Catch ex As Exception
        objResp = Nothing
        objResp.Close()
        objWebReq = Nothing
        Return False
 End Try
```

So if user falls in this case (we hope user do not) I was thinking to wait to finish like 5 seconds if it does not finist getting response just stop `objWebReq.GetResponse` and then return False.
But the great question is:

how can I measure time of objWebReq.GetResponse and wait 5 seconds
if is taking more than 5 seconds break and return false
else return true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your request to timeout after 5 seconds.

See [WebRequest.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) for full details.

If a timeout happens, an exception will be thrown that you should catch and properly handle.

> Descendant classes signal a timeout by throwing a WebException with the Status field set to WebExceptionStatus.Timeout. When Timeout is set to Timeout.Infinite the descendant class does not time out.

Comment: Beat me to saying that.